# Pyemd module installed in virtual environment but Module not found error?

Tags: python, package, virtualenv

I installed pyemd within my virtual environment. However, when I got to Jupyter Notebook or Python within the command line it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyemd'`.

```
 . venv-new/bin/activate #activating environment

  (venv-new) pip install pyemd #installing pyemd
```

Output:

```
  Requirement already satisfied: pyemd in ./venv-new/lib/python3.9/site-packages (0.5.1)
  Requirement already satisfied: numpy<2.0.0,>=1.9.0 in ./venv-new/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pyemd) (1.22.3)
```

Activating Python:

```
(venv-new) python
Python 3.9.6 (v3.9.6:db3ff76da1, Jun 28 2021, 11:49:53)
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyemd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyemd'
```

I have tried solutions such as specifying the path:

```
(venv-new) Users/path/to/enviro/venv-new/bin/python -m pip install pyemd
```

I have tried just:

```
(venv-new) python -m pip install pyemd
```

and

```
(venv-new) python3.9 -m pip install pyemd
```

All these solutions resulted in the same output when activating Python. I can't use sudo since I don't have the proper permissions.

Comment: Because you mention inside Jupyter having the same issue, it may be worth trying from inside a cell in a notebook in this environment, running `%pip install pyemd`. At least to know if that gives anything different.

Comment: Using that works! Thanks! What does % do as opposed to  ! ?

Comment: For both `pip` and `conda` a magic command was added in the last few years to insure installation to the correct environment backing your notebook, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). Anything you see with an exclamation for `pip` and `conda` is outdated. The magic commands were added for exactly the reasons you ran into. As an aside, I wonder if you ran `ipython` in the console and ran that same command, if it would also fix it so Python in the console works? May just be wishful thinking there.

Comment: I should add that because of auto-magics usually being on in most Jupyter installls these days, the `%` usually will get added behind the scenes to run the magic command if you just type `pip` or `conda` in a Jupyter cell. In other words, as long as you don't have an exclamation point for `pip` or `conda` you usually will now have a better experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to @Wayne for the answer in the comments!
I had been using the following command within Jupyter but didn't know it was outdad.

```
!pip install pyemd
```

The solution for me was using

```
%pip install pyemd
```